# how recived data in flutter blue plus

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I am using this package
characteristics but how can I get a specific character

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: unable to understand the issues properly . Please add proper explanation . I am working on Flutter Blue Plus Plugin . i may help you .

Comment: If you follow this doc https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus properly . It will solve your issues . I has scan Ble device . connect,disconnect , read charactericts  etc ...

Comment: You should declare some required permissions for Blutooth in AndroidManifest file .

Answer (score 0):

To read the ***characteristic*** from **BLe device**. Read this [Flutter_blue_plus doc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus)

```
// Reads all characteristics and verify your characteristics
var characteristics = service.characteristics;
for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
    if (c.properties.read) {
        List<int> value = await c.read();
        print(value);
    }
}
```

or Verify the chareterists while connecting the BLE Device

```
  Future<DeviceStatus> connectBleDevice() async {
    // Protection from dropping good connection to device
    if (_currentStatus != DeviceStatus.disconnected &&
        _currentStatus != DeviceStatus.error) {
      return _currentStatus;
    }

    _currentStatus = DeviceStatus.connecting;
    try {
      // Try to disconnect from the device if it was already connected
      await _device.disconnect();

      // Connect to device (if fail the we will receive exception)
      await _device
          .connect(autoConnect: false)
          .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3));

      var filteredStateStream = _device.connectionState
          .where((s) => s == BluetoothConnectionState.connected);

      // Start listening now, before invokeMethod, to ensure we don't miss the response
      Future<BluetoothConnectionState> futureState = filteredStateStream.first;

      // wait for connection
      await futureState.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
        throw TimeoutException('Failed to connect in time.');
      });
      _currentStatus = DeviceStatus.connected;

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        await _device.requestMtu(256);
      }

      _bleDeviceServices = await _device.discoverServices();

      if (_verifyDeviceCharacteristic() == false) {
        _currentStatus = DeviceStatus.error;
      }

      // We need to setup subscription for the data that comes from device
      try {
        if (_nusTxCharacteristic!.isNotifying == false) {
          await _nusTxCharacteristic!.setNotifyValue(true);
        }
        // We need to clear the buffer from previous data (possible)
        _receivedDataBuffer.clear();
        _subscriptionForDataFromDevice =
            _nusTxCharacteristic!.onValueReceived.listen((binaryData) {
          loggy.debug('Data received from the device!');
          _receivedDataBuffer.write(bytesToString(binaryData));
          jsonFile = Stream.value(_receivedDataBuffer);
        });
        _device.cancelWhenDisconnected(_subscriptionForDataFromDevice!);
      } catch (error) {
        loggy.error('Error during connection', error);
        _currentStatus = DeviceStatus.error;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _currentStatus = DeviceStatus.disconnected;
    }
    return _currentStatus;
  }
```

And then you can verify the list of your characterists as follows:-

```
 bool _verifyDeviceCharacteristic() {
    try {
      final deviceInformationService = _bleDeviceServices.firstWhere(
          (service) => service.uuid == deviceInformationServiceGuid);

      // Here we want to find device information characteristics
      _manufacturerNameCharacteristic = deviceInformationService.characteristics
          .firstWhere((characteristic) =>
              characteristic.uuid == manufacturerNameStringCharacteristicGuid);
      _modelNumberCharacteristic = deviceInformationService.characteristics
          .firstWhere((characteristic) =>
              characteristic.uuid == modelNumberStringCharacteristicGuid);
      _serialNumberCharacteristic = deviceInformationService.characteristics
          .firstWhere((characteristic) =>
              characteristic.uuid == serialNumberStringCharacteristicGuid);
      _hardwareRevisionCharacteristic = deviceInformationService.characteristics
          .firstWhere((characteristic) =>
              characteristic.uuid == hardwareRevisionStringCharacteristicGuid);
      _softwareRevisionCharacteristic = deviceInformationService.characteristics
          .firstWhere((characteristic) =>
              characteristic.uuid == softwareRevisionStringCharacteristicGuid);
    } on StateError catch (e) {
      loggy.error("Device Information Service wasn't found!", e);
      return false;
    }

    try {
      final nordicUartServiceService = _bleDeviceServices
          .firstWhere((service) => service.uuid == nordicUartServiceGuid);

      // Here we want to find Tx and Rx characteristics
      try {
        _nusTxCharacteristic = nordicUartServiceService.characteristics
            .firstWhere((characteristic) =>
                characteristic.uuid == nordicUartServiceTxCharacteristicGuid);
      } on StateError catch (e) {
        loggy.error("Nordic UART Service TX characteristic wasn't found!", e);
        rethrow;
      }

      try {
        _nusRxCharacteristic = nordicUartServiceService.characteristics
            .firstWhere((characteristic) =>
                characteristic.uuid == nordicUartServiceRxCharacteristicGuid);
      } on StateError catch (e) {
        loggy.error("Nordic UART Service RX characteristic wasn't found!", e);
        rethrow;
      }
    } on StateError catch (e) {
      loggy.error("Nordic UART Service wasn't found!", e);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```